# Writing to a subfolder in c#

Tags: c#, directory

I'm having a little bit of trouble writing to a text file within a folder I tried to create. It said I didn't have access to the path 'C:\'

Could anyone tell me why and how to fix it? Thanks!

```
string file_name = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
    file_name += @"\.";
    file_name = (string)combobox1.SelectedValue;
    file_name += @"\.";
    file_name += (string)combobox2.SelectedValue;
    TextWriter name = new StreamWriter(file_name);
```

EDIT: Here's the new code after revisions...

```
var location = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, (string)combobox1.SelectedItem);
Directory.CreateDirectory(location);
var path = Path.Combine(location, combobox2.SelectedItem);
TextWriter name = new StreamWriter(path, true);
```

My goal is to write a text file to \\.txt

Could anyone tell me how? Thanks!

Comment: how do i check? is there an easier way to make it write to the current directory then a subfolder on top of that? so like "..\new folder\text.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution here is a combination of what everyone else has said.

As has already been pointed out, this line:

```
file_name = (string)combobox1.SelectedValue;
```

is incorrectly doing an assignment (`=`) instead of a concatenation (`+=`).  This means that if `comboxbo1.SelectedValue` is `null`, your path becomes `\.`, which is the root directory of the drive.

You need to remember that it's legal for `SelectedValue` to be `null`, because a combo box can have an empty selection.  You need to handle that case, perhaps by disabling your save functionality until the combo boxes have valid selections.

This isn't really a problem with permissions; it's unlikely that you actually need or intend to write to the root directory, which is why you aren't given that permission in the first place.

Comment: I've implemented my code since then to adapt my code so it now goes to the correct directory. However, I'm getting a DirectoryNotFoundException was unhandled error. Am I somehow creating the folder wrong?

Comment: Nothing in your code is creating a directory.  If you need to ensure that the directory exists before creating a file there, use Directory.CreateDirectory().  This method will automatically create any necessary subdirectories.

Comment: Okay, so I then ran into the problem that on top of having an UnauthorizedAccessException was unhandled error, it was creating two folders, so I removed the second combobox from the combine statement. My goal is to create a text file in <current directory>\<combobox1>\text.txt

Comment: Create a variable to hold the file _location_: var location = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, (string)combobox1.SelectedValue).  Create another variable to hold the file _path_, which is the location plus the filename: var path = Path.Combine(location, "text.txt").  To create the directory, use the location.  To create the file, use the path.

Comment: sorry for not being clear, the "text.txt" isn't a set filename. It will change according to the value of combobox2. However, when I try to replace "text.txt" with combobox2.SelectedItem, it throws an error

Answer (score 1):

have you checked the value of file_name to make sure is a valid Path?

you have missed a concatenation anyway at line number 3

```
string file_name = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
    file_name += @"\.";
    file_name += (string)combobox1.SelectedValue;  // <--
    file_name += @"\.";
    file_name += (string)combobox2.SelectedValue;
    TextWriter name = new StreamWriter(file_name);
```

Answer (score 1):

The account that the application is running under does not have write permissions in the location you are trying to save the file to.

This article goes over how to resolve this issue:

http://www.phdcc.com/findinsite/instperm.htm

Answer (score 1):

You should be using [`Path.Combine()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991142.aspx):

```
var fileName = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, (string)comboBox1.SelectedValue,
                            (string)comboBox2.SelectedValue);
```

If at that point it still doesn't work, at least you'll know it's actually a permissions/existence/etc. issue, rather than an issue with the way you've constructed the file name.

Comment: I tried this, but got this error:

Argument NullException was unhandled. Why is that?

Comment: how do i set permissions/existence issues?

Comment: @Alex you got that exception because one of the arguments you passed was `null`. That's probably your problem. Set a breakpoint on the line, and inspect to see which one, and then fix that!

Comment: Hmmmm it seems both of my comboboxes were null, but I don't know why. Should I be using something else instead of SelectedValue?

Comment: Never mind, I used SelectedText, and it got rid of the error. Is that right? When I debug it, it just says "" instead of null now. Is that okay? But now I get the permission error. is there code i can write to make it writable?

Comment: @Alex Were you expecting an empty string?

Comment: No, but I just tried SelectedItem and that worked. However I'm getting a DirectoryNotFoundException was unhandled. I thought it would create the file if it wasn't there. Why isn't it?